# How find MongoDB data on server. Code deployed by Docker?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, docker, server, nosql

I have deployed my code by Docker. But, I want to insert some data in my database manual(Like Local database, Terminal). I am unable to insert find my database on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can also explore to run Mongo container with some seeds data so you will not required extra effort to insert data every time when you run the container.

**Initializing a fresh instance**

> When a container is started for the first time it will execute files
>   with extensions .sh and .js that are found in
>   `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. Files will be executed in alphabetical
>   order. `.js` files will be executed by mongo using the database
>   specified by the `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE` variable, if it is present, or
>   test otherwise. You may also switch databases within the `.js` script.

If you are looking easy way docker mongo DB plus with mongo-client then you can try this

```
# Use root/example as user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
```

You can import, export and create Database.
[image]

[image]

Comment: How you connect your compass editor to server. Actually, I am unable to do this. What Images you have shared.

Comment: create a file `docker-compose.yml` and paste the above yml config and then just run `docker-compose up`